# Permission denied at createNewFile() in /sdcard

Tags: android

i have a piece of code, which creates a file on the /sdcard on the ExternalStorage ("internal" 8GB Memory of a GalaxyTab2 7.0).

```
directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "/logs");
directory.mkdirs();
log = new File(directory.getPath() + "/" + this.filename);
boolean created = log.createNewFile();
```

At the last line i get following error:

```
... java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
...     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
```

I have

- set the permission for writing external storage in the right place in manifest
- checked, that the memory is not mounted at pc
- checked, that the /logs/ folder hat the correct permissions at file explorer
- read every single stackoverflow thread about the topic - nothing worked

Has anyone a hint, which can cause this behavior?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a (self-written) library, which manages all the memory access. This library project has the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. The App, which references this library must also have this permission, even if it is not directly accessing the storage.

Answer (score 2):

add below permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```